# Use the standard coinfloor API in Python with working credentials creates an error message: WebSocketException

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

The link to the git is: [github.com/coinfloor/python-library](https://github.com/coinfloor/python-library)

There are only 2 files.

1. the support file - [github.com/coinfloor/python-library/blob/master/coinfloor.py](https://github.com/coinfloor/python-library/blob/master/coinfloor.py)
2. the code - https://github.com/coinfloor/python-library/blob/master/clientExample.py

I parse the required credentials (which i know work from successful code in `node.js` using the same credentials).
There are only 4 credentials:

1. url ("wss://api.coinfloor.co.uk/")
2. coinfloor id (which is a 4 digit number)
3. cookie (API key)
4. password

This goes into the argparse module which the calls the next routine invoking the support file `coinfloor.com`.
I do not touch or edit this file as it "*should be*" working.

When i run the process, the program fails on `line 233` of the `coinfloor.py` file.

The error message reads:
`Exception has occurred: WebSocketException socket is already opened`

My understanding of reading the error message is that the socket (`websocket`) has somehow been opened previously in the code. If this is the case, how can i prevent such ?

I have read up about websockets but dont understand what i need to do to fix this error.

- python version: `3.9`
- import websocket using `pip install websocket-client`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the library.  Apply this pull request to fix it:

https://github.com/coinfloor/python-library/pull/1

The bugs are corrected and the login details slightly ammended:

- website = `wss://apiv2.coinfloor.co.uk/`
- password to the `website login password` in place of the v1 password.

This works.

Comment: Thank you,  i will go through the changes.    i note the change of asset currency             `counter = Assets["USD"],`
`counter = Assets["GBP"],`  and also the error handler      `def _err_handler(self, ws, error):`
    `def _err_handler(self, error):`

Comment: I use the new fix, which works to an extent. However, line 66 of the clientExample.py file `coinfloor.GetBalances()` throws an error:  `Exception has occurred: TypeError
_err_handler() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

Comment: comment left here:   https://github.com/coinfloor/python-library/pull/1#pullrequestreview-596606376